# How do I trim bytes from the beginning and end of a file?

Tags: files, trim, byte

I have a file, that has trash (binary header and footer) at the beginning and end of the file. I would like to know how to nuke these bytes. For an example, let's assume 25 bytes from the beginning. And, 2 bytes from the end.

I know I can use truncate and dd, but truncate doesn't work with a stream and it seems kind of cludgey to run two commands on the hard file. It would be nicer if `truncate`, knowing how big the file was, could cat the file to `dd`. Or, if there was a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can combine GNU [`tail`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html#tail-invocation) and [`head`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html#head-invocation):

```
tail -c +26 file | head -c -2
```

will output the contents of `file` starting at byte 26, and stopping two bytes (minus two `-2`) before the end. (`-c` operates on bytes, not characters.)

Comment: Note that `tail -c +26` is standard (`head -c -2` is not).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is there a POSIX compliant version of the `head -c -2` command?

Comment: This does not work well when the file contains null bytes, right?

Comment: @Zorglub29 it works for me even with null bytes.

Answer (score 12):

**dd** will do both for you in a single command. Set the block size to 1 byte, skip the 25 first bytes, count to the size of file minus skip and end bytes.

```
100 byte file
file.img
```

`dd if=./file.img of=./trimed_file.img bs=1 skip=25 count=73`

Double check numbers cause it might count from 0.

Comment: isn't too slow?

Comment: Too slow? Only if the file is very large like many GB. Then you could adjust the block size.

Comment: it took 0m8.319s for a 1.3 MB file, For the count he can use something  like `$(( `stat -c %s test` - 5 ))` I guess.

Comment: Remember that skip and count are blocks not bytes. Pick the largest multiple for the block size. The closer the block size is to the HD buffer size the more efficient and faster the command is.

Comment: Yeah, however bs is defined 1 in your command :-) so in this case it will work...

Comment: with `bs=1` dd makes two system calls for each byte, that's horribly slow. GNU dd has the `count_bytes` and `skip_bytes` that can help, do something like `dd bs=8192 iflag=count_bytes,skip_bytes skip=25 count=73 < infile > outfile`

Answer (score 2):

With ksh93:

```
{ head -c "$n"; } < file <#((n = EOF - 25 - 2 , 25))
```

Or to do it in-place:

```
{ head -c "$n"; } < file <#((n = EOF - 25 - 2 , 25)) 1<>; file
```

If you have `/opt/ast/bin` ahead of your `$PATH`, you'll get the `head` builtin.

- `<#((...))` is a `lseek()` operator. `...` is interpreted as an arithmetic expression where `EOF` is the length of the file. So above, we're assigning the length of the portion to display to `$n` and seeking to 25 bytes within the file.
- `<>;` is a open-in-read+write-mode-and-truncate-if-the-command-is-successful redirection   operator.